PHP alert pop up message before load code
I have a home server with my raspberry pi project. I am trying to add to my code a pop up alert to inform user a message before running the rest code.
<?php
//Message to user
echo '<script>alert("Do you want to continue?")</script>';

//Rest Code
//Python Code
shell_exec('sudo python3 /home/pi/test.py');
//Redirect
header("Location: https://www.google.com/");
//ShutDown
//system('sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
        <!-- container -->
</body>
</html>

If alert answer is OK or Yes to load the rest code.

One of the ways: use ajax

@Ken Lee or function but i have not managed to make it work

You've forgotten that php runs first, on the webserver, before the page is loaded into the browser. Then when the page is delivered from the server into the browser, javascript can run. So the code won't execute in the sequence you've assumed here. If you want php to do something as a result of a choice made by the user in their browser, that needs to be as a result of a subsequent http request to the server in order to trigger a new script, passing in the choice as a parameter. In this scenario, ajax is a good option for doing that

@ADyson As it is a home server and project, i can remove html and focus on PHP pure code

Yes you could just call the php script directly with the choice parameter in the URL (like the example below). Or you could use a html form rather than javascript. Depends how much of a friendly user interface you want to create for yourself

You have to use JavaScript confirm to take actions based on user action
check below modified code
index.php

    <?php

     if(isset($_GET['action']) and $_GET['action']!=''){
       
         $action = $_GET['action'];
         if($action=='yes'){
            // Your Code
            //Python Code
           shell_exec('sudo python3 /home/pi/test.py');
         } 
          
         if($action=='no'){
            // Your code 
            //Redirect
             header("Location: https://www.google.com/");
             //ShutDown
             //system('sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now');
         }  
         
     }

      
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
        
   <script type="text/javascript">

       function askuser() {

        var ask = window.confirm("Do you want to continue?");
         if (ask) {
           window.location.href = "./index.php?action=yes";
         }else{
           window.location.href = "./index.php?action=no";
         }
       }
   </script>

   <button name="button" type="button" onclick="askuser();" >Action</button>


</body>
</html>


You can also prompt on document load by onload method on body

<?php
         if(isset($_GET['action']) and $_GET['action']!=''){
           
             $action = $_GET['action'];
             if($action=='yes'){
                // Your Code
                //Python Code
               shell_exec('sudo python3 /home/pi/test.py');
             } 
              
             if($action=='no'){
                // Your code 
                //Redirect
                 header("Location: https://www.google.com/");
                 //ShutDown
                 //system('sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now');
             }  
             
         }
        ?>
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
     
         <script type="text/javascript">

           function askuser() {  
            var ask = window.confirm("Do you want to continue?");
             if (ask) {
               window.location.href = "./index.php?action=yes";
             }else{
               window.location.href = "./index.php?action=no";
             }
           }
       </script>
     </head>
       <body onload="askuser();">
     </body>
     </html>


